# Is there a language that's purely fluid-s?

Tags: semantics, morphology

By fluid-s I mean a stative-active language that relies on semantics for its morphosyntactic alignment, using things such as volition, empathy, animacy.

Comment: What do you mean by "purely"? Crow evidently has two lexically determined verb classes "Active" and "Stative" - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think that's it.

Comment: I once read about Fluid-S languages in a book called "Ergativity" by R.M.W. Dixon.   He contrasts subjects of intransitive verbs (S) with the subjects of transitive verbs (A) with the objects of transitive verbs (O).   In nominative/accusative languages, like English and Finnish, S and A are marked identically.    In ergative/absolutive languages, some verbs or other circumstances dictate that S is marked just like O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Crow language (Apsáalooke) [divides verbs into two classes, "Active" and "Stative"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crow_language#Verbal_morphology). The division between classes is based on semantic criteria. The objects of transitive active verbs are marked like the subjects of stative verbs, and there is a different set of pronominal affixes for each verb type.